# Does Windows 2008 R2 Desktop Experience include Windows 7 features?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, windows-server-2008

You could enable desktop features with Windows 2008 and get an experience close to Windows Vista. Is it still the same experience with R2, or have they included Windows 7 features like the new Taskbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, Windows 2008 R2 (also called Windows Server 7) has the Windows 7 Taskbar. You can see it in screenshots [here](http://www.jcxp.net/screenshots/winserver08r2/).

You may also want to read [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/01/09/windows-server-2008-r2-beta-aero-enabled-workstation/) blog post by Doug Holland from Intel.

Comment: screenshots URL not working, giving 404 error

Comment: Yeah they seem to have deleted it. Anyway, heres a new article showing how to get Windows 7 wallpapers onto Server 2008, so you can see 2008 looking like 7 with the wallpaper and all: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/02/28/windows-7-beta-fish-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes the new taskbar is part of Windows 2008 R2, it is available even without the desktop features enabled.  R2 also includes the keyboard shortcuts to move windows.