# Does Windows Server 2008 R2 Web will be good for normal pc?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, workstation

I got Windows Server 2008 R2 Web free version from webspark,

I want to use this version for my pc, is it nice or should work on a server, is it the same as windows 7 except the UI?

Can you advice?

i am a web developer and need a good os to develop on, must be fast and powerful in the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/18303/why-would-you-use-windows-server-as-a-desktop-operating-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Windows Server 2008 as a workstation for about 6 months and was satisfied with it for the most part with one caveat.  Many applications require you to purchase their "server" versions.  The normal "workstation" versions won't work.  Of course, the server versions cost anywhere from 3 to 10 times as much.

If you're willing to pay the premium for some server applications, then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

This **tutorial** will help you to install **Microsoft Windows Server 2008** and to configure your pc so you can use it as a **workstation**:

**[Convert your Windows Server 2008 to a Workstation](http://www.win2008workstation.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

Found this [question and its answe](https://superuser.com/questions/18289/does-windows-2008-r2-desktop-experience-include-windows-7-features)r, may answer part of my question